# How can i use one template on different pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I use one **template** on **different pages** in **WordPress**? If I am using template the WordPress page content is not showing, and if I am not using the WordPress template then only I can see my template.

Comment: Hi Rahul, can you include the content of your WordPress template itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one template in different pages in WordPress by assigning the page template option on the right drop down to the template you want to use.

[image]

if you want to create a custom page and use it as a template in your website you can find detailed steps [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/), just remember to change the top of your template comment

```
     <?php
/*
Template Name: write here your custom name for template 
*/
get_header(); ?>
```